# Angular ag-Grid: custom cell renderer that turns on edit mode over all editable cells in row

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have some problems with making custom cell renderer with menu for edit all row in one click.

[image]

First of all I want to render menu icon, on user click the dropdown shows and I select 'edit' option (don't bother about remove option). Ok so I have visual aspect of cell in the definiton of the column:

```
columnsDefinition.push({
  headerName: '',
  cellRendererFramework: EditRendererComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {
    // params will be here
  }
});
```

Ok lets go to the next step. I need some extra params, I know how to pass static params of component, but I also need data from the row where my cell is rendered - I don't know how to pass it to the custom renderer component.

This is my EditRendererComponent:

```
export class EditRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  isEditing = false;
  params: any;

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams) {
this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(params: any): boolean {
return false;
  }

editMode() {
// we need to loop thru all rows, find the column with the renderer, and 'cancel the edit mode'.
// otherwise, we will end up with rows that has SAVE buttons appearing but not in edit mode
const renderersInOtherRows = this.params.api.getCellRendererInstances(this.params);

if( renderersInOtherRows && renderersInOtherRows.length > 0 ) {
  for(const wrapper of renderersInOtherRows) {
    if (wrapper.getFrameworkComponentInstance() instanceof EditRendererComponent ) {
      const foundRenderer = wrapper.getFrameworkComponentInstance() as EditRendererComponent;
      if( foundRenderer.isEditing ) {
        foundRenderer.onCancel();
      }
    }
  }
}
this.isEditing = true;
this.params.api.startEditingCell( { rowIndex: this.params.node.rowIndex, colKey: 'some-col-field-name'});
}

onCancel() {
this.isEditing = false;
// restore previous data or reload
}
onSave() {
this.isEditing = false;
// do your saving logic
}
}
```

Summary, I need help with:

1) Pass record data to the renderer component

2) `editMode()` method doesn't work at all, any ideas how it should be resolved to make all cells editable (only when columns def `editable` is set to true)?

Comment: your question about edit mode is unclear. I would suggest to either edit it or split it into separate questions

Comment: @PratikBhat I want to achive excatly the same thing like default fullRow edit mode, but on button (that I render in customCellRenderer) click: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-full-row-editing and the button makes only his row editable

Comment: updated the answer for edit mode ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not pass data through `cellRendererParams`. Inside your cell renderer component you can access row data using params.

```
  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    data = params.data // access row data here
  }
```

If you take a look at this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-full-row-edit) from docs, you need to implement your button click similar to the example. The way you have it in your code should do the trick.

You just need to add  `[suppressClickEdit] = true` to your `gridOption` so edit is activated only via button click. And you are ensuring only the current row is active for editing by passing `rowIndex` to the `startEditing` api.

Your `editMode()` which I assume is called on click of edit button should be really simple something like this -

```
editMode() {
this.params.api.startEditingCell( { rowIndex: this.params.node.rowIndex, colKey: 'some-col-field-name'});
}
```